# HTMLEncodes Image URL and breaks the image

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I am have simple script where i save news details like `News Title, News URL and News Image URL`. i noticed that image doesn't show when it has Unicode characters take for example `http://www.bbj.hu/images2/201412/párizsi_ud_20141218113410452.jpg`

It is stored in database as it is but when i display it on web page breaks & shows as 
`http://www.bbj.hu/images2/201412/pa%c2%b4rizsi_ud_20141218113410452.jpg`

When i debug my asp.net webform page it show correctly in the code behind

```
 protected String getImage(object imgSource)
    {
        string img = null;
        img = imgSource.ToString();
        return img;
```

// Debug show image url properly but it breaks on actual page
        }

**.aspx code**

```
  <asp:Image ID="NewsImage" ImageUrl='<%# getImage(Eval("NewsImageURL")) %>'  runat="server"  />
```

I tried different things but it keeps showing up as `http://www.bbj.hu/images2/201412/pa%c2%b4rizsi_ud_20141218113410452.jpg`

How can i fix this

Answer (score 0):

Your problem's solution must be among one or more of the following:

**C# URL Encode/Decode:**

```
string encodedUrl = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(myUrl);
string sameMyUrl = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(encodedUrl);
```

**Javascript URL Encode/Decode:**

```
function myFunction() {
    var uri = myUrl;
    var uri_enc = encodeURIComponent(uri);
    var uri_dec = decodeURIComponent(uri_enc);
}
```

**C# HTML Encode/Decode:**

```
string encodedHtml = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(myHtml);
string sameMyHtml = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(encodedHtml);
```

**Javascript HTML Encode/Decode:**

```
function htmlEncode(value) {
     //create a in-memory div, set its inner text (which jQuery automatically encodes)
     //then grab the encoded contents back out. The div never exists on the page.
     return $('<div/>').text(value).html();
}

function htmlDecode(html) {
    return $('<div>').html(html).text();
}
```